# Is it safe to use virtual mobile numbers for verification

Tags: authentication, mobile, service-account

Is it safe to use virtual mobile numbers for account verification & authentication for services such as PayPal, Twitter, Gmail, Linkekdin, etc.? And what is the security drawback for this?

Answer (score 2):

The question is whether its a one time use and forget, or is it kept in their database and used for future verification

If you are certainly sure that it is a one time usage, I don't think there is any problem using a virtual number.

If not, you might end up losing control of the account if you are required for that number (two factor auth for example) or in a very rare case someone else who currently has that virtual number can gain control over your account (more science fiction than reality)

Comment: Even if kept in the database, once I use it, it can't be used again in case of 2FA correct. Similar case, when using normal mobile number SMS messages can be intercepted, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

its getting tough to use the online numbers for verification. Last time I try with one application, but they are using missed call mobile verification ( some thing like Cognalys)
and the virtual numbers are not showing any call logs. The last five digits from the missed call number was the OTP... :)

Comment: Cognalys are using different method. Anyhow thanks for the info.